# apk file parsing

Tags: android

Each and every android application is bundled as an apk file. When an apk file is installed different entites (files) of the application are stored in different parts of the system. For example i have found that real player stores its files in the following places of the android file system
    `/data/data/com.real.RealPlayer
    /data/app/com.real.RealPlayer-1.apk
    /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.real.RealPlayer-1.apk@classes.dex
    /data/system/packages.list
    /data/system/packages.xml
    /data/data/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/databases/launcher.db`

How can i do this for every installed application on my phone/emulator?? Is it the right way to parse apk file and find the places where all the parts of the app are stored?? Any ideas?

Comment: You can only do this on emulator and rooted phones. Most phones are not rooted.

Comment: Ya i have rooted my phone...can u suggest any way of finding the places where the app's files are stored?

Comment: Any ideas of where an application's files are stored in android file system?

Answer (score 0):

On normal non-rooted phones an application can see only its own files, due to [security restrictions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html).

Comment: Ya true...but my phone is now rooted..how can i see all files of any application ?